# Processing XML prolog by SQL Server XML functions

Tags: sql-server, xml, xpath, xquery

I have a large database table with an XML column. The XML contents is a kind of document like as below:

```
<?int-dov version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<ds:datastoreItem ds:itemID="{F8484AF4-73BF-45CA-A524-0D796F244F37}" xmlns:ds="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/customXml"><ds:schemaRefs><ds:schemaRef ds:uri="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/bibliography"/></ds:schemaRefs></ds:datastoreItem>
```

I'm seeking a function or fast way to fetch standalone attribute value in a T-SQL query. When I run the below query:

```
select  XmlContent.query('@standalone') from XmlDocuments
```

I get this error message:

```
Msg 2390, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
XQuery [XmlDocuments.XmlContent.query()]: Top-level attribute nodes are not supported
```

So, I would be appreciated if anybody gives me a solution to address this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`processing-instruction()` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/xquery/path-expressions-specifying-node-test?view=sql-server-ver15#node-type-as-node-test) to get that.

```sql
SELECT @xml.value('./processing-instruction("int-dov")[1]','nvarchar(max)')
```

| **Result** |
| --- |
| version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" |

If you want to get just the `standalone` part, the only way I've found is to construct an XML node from it:

```sql
SELECT CAST(
  N'<x ' +
  @xml.value('./processing-instruction("int-dov")[1]','nvarchar(max)') +
  N' />' AS xml).value('x[1]/@standalone','nvarchar(10)'
```

| **Result** |
| --- |
| no |

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2717747c8c95f6342a2ee9eb3a515e41)

Comment: Good answer, +1 from my side!

Comment: Do *you* have a way of parsing the `processing-instruction`? It seems to only return the whole thing as a string

Comment: I am unaware about such functionality in  SQL Server XQuery. Please up-vote my suggestion: https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/153a9604-7025-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0da0

Answer (score 0):

Just to complement @Charlieface answer. All credit goes to him.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @xml XML = 
N'<?int-dov version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<ds:datastoreItem ds:itemID="{F8484AF4-73BF-45CA-A524-0D796F244F37}"
                  xmlns:ds="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/customXml">
    <ds:schemaRefs>
        <ds:schemaRef ds:uri="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/bibliography"/>
    </ds:schemaRefs>
</ds:datastoreItem>';

SELECT col.value('x[1]/@standalone','nvarchar(10)') AS [standalone]
    , col.value('x[1]/@encoding','nvarchar(10)') AS [encoding]
    , col.value('x[1]/@version','nvarchar(10)') AS [version]
FROM (VALUES(CAST(N'<x ' +
  @xml.value('./processing-instruction("int-dov")[1]','nvarchar(max)') +
  N' />' AS xml))
) AS tab(col);
```

**Output**

```
+------------+----------+---------+
| standalone | encoding | version |
+------------+----------+---------+
| no         | UTF-8    |     1.0 |
+------------+----------+---------+
```